# How to decrypt packet data?

Tags: android, encryption, tcpdump

I have capture the packet in android device by using tcpdump but the packet data is in encrypted format. how can i get decrypted data. I have found the packet  data as...

[image: packet data]

actually i got got the more information in this format which in not human readable.

[image: data image]

Comment: That's not encrypted - the packets begin with 0x45, which looks *very* much like the first byte of an IPv4 header with no options (the "4" is the IP version and the "5" is the header length in 32-bit words, so 20 bytes, which is the size of an IPv4 header with no options), and, in fact, tcpdump is printing them as two DNS queries with an ICMP Destination Unreachable message between them.  So what leads you to think the packets are encrypted?

Comment: Hi, Guy Harris i have found the data in the above format in next pic which is not a human readable, how can i get the information from this data.

Comment: 'Not human readable' != 'encrypted'. You need to have a look at the DNS and ICMP protocols.

Comment: What's the entire printout for the packet in your second image (not the "oui Unknown" packet, the packet before that, as I assume that's the packet to which you're referring)?  I.e., what are all the hex digits, and what was the packet line tcpdump printed before that?